# JOGL, after using an image for texture, colors are off

Tags: java, image, textures, jogl

So basically, in making a game. Instead of having big blocks of certain colors to make the terrain, i decided to try to have some images of already existing pictures of terrain. So i went on this tutorial:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jogl/jogl_3d_cube.htm

I've managed to make the picture appear on screen but for some reason the colors are always slightly darker. I took out all existing objects to see if they had an impact on the image but it remains the same. So now there it is alone in the "void". Background is black btw.

Oh if you're wondering about those commentary on update, pause and resume methods, those methods aren't really required. SceneObject is a scene object meaning it has an impact on the scene(world), it can do stuff(update) be drawn(drawInternal) and pause/resume (affects behavior of update and draw, saves time when it was paused mostly due to timers(bombs etc...)).

Oh and why do i have a boolean (doneLoading) for the creation of the image? Normally i would have done it on MapTexture() like all sceneObjects but since it required gl, i delayed its creation to the first time it runs the draw method. It appears to have worked, the only problem is the slight difference in color, again slightly darker.

```
package backGround;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.media.opengl.GL2;
import javax.media.opengl.GLException;

import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO;

public class MapTexture extends cgglClasses.SceneObject{

private int texture;
private boolean doneLoading = false;

public MapTexture(){

}
@Override
public void update(long currentMs, long deltaMs, float deltaS) {
    // probably does nothing?
}
@Override
protected void drawInternal(GL2 gl) {
    if(!doneLoading){
        try {
            //gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            URL url = getClass().getResource("/resourcesImg/e1.jpg");
            Texture t = TextureIO.newTexture(url, true, null);
            //Texture t = TextureIO.newTexture(img, true);
            texture = t.getTextureObject(gl);
            //gl.glClearColor(0f,0f,0f,0f);
            //gl.glClearDepth(1f);
            gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);
            gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
            doneLoading = true;
        } catch (GLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    gl.glPushMatrix();

    //gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, 10f);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f); gl.glVertex3f(-10f, 0f, -10f);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f); gl.glVertex3f(10f, 0f, -10f);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f); gl.glVertex3f(10f, 0f, 10f);
        gl.glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f); gl.glVertex3f(-10f, 0f, 10f);
    gl.glEnd();

    //

    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glDisable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // does absolutely nothing
}
@Override
public void resume() {
    //as above so below
}
}
```

So if you have any idea on what the missing link please reply. Its probably a minor thing i'm missing but i just cant seem to find it.

****************************  UPDATE ********************************

Ok so somehow its fixed, but with some serious hacks. Inserts random Hackerman meme.

So i noticed that when i tried to use a color on a text that was supposed to appear on screen(text not texture), i used the color red to make it noticeable. Now i wasn't able to find the text but instead the whole previous texture from before was super red. Like just red and black. It looked like lava which is cool but it was weird. So i tried using black and as expected was all black. Then i tried white and voila. Finally the texture had the true colors i so desperately wanted.

So before gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); i just added gl.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f); which represents white in RGB.

Why it works, i'm guessing the color red stayed there affecting the image colors matrix, using white it now affects all colors. Is there  a better way to solve or am i missing something. I've followed the tutorial and must have tried solutions from over 5 solved answers that were similar to my code. None worked but this works somehow.

Comment: Don't follow that tutorial, it uses [deprecated OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL). I made a port of a modern one [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples)

Comment: Moreover, you use an obsolete minor version of JOGL. Rather switch to JOGL 2.3.2 and provide a SSCCE if you want to get some help. You complain about other solutions but you don't provide a complete example. Where do you call glClear()?